# FragmentPagerAdapter did NOT change fragment contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

FragmentPagerAdapter By Project Wizard

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new ChapterPageFragment();
        if (currentPart != null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            Chapter chapter =  currentPart.getChapters().get(position);
            if (chapter.getVerses() == null) {
                chapter.setVerses(currentDao.readVerses(currentPart, chapter));
            }
            args.putParcelable(Chapter.KEY, currentPart.getChapters().get(position));
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (currentPart == null) {
            return 0;   // Before Initialzing
        }
        return currentPart.getChapterCount();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return getString(R.string.chapter_format, position+1);
    }
}
```

When Change Data

```
 actionListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                currentPart = currentBook.getParts().get(position);
                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                slideMenu.showContent();
            }
        });
```

View Page Count is changed, But page (fragment) contents did not changed.

For example,

Select A Part, 3 Pages: "A1", "A2", "A3"

Then Select B Part, 5 Pages: **"A1", "A2", "A3"**, "B4", "B5" *(not "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")*

How can I change page contents A to B?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it will solve your issue.